# Put Postgres query result in array

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, c#, array

How can I put an sql query result in a string array with Postgres?
I have some attributes in the column 'zone' of the table 'mytable' and I must put them all in a `String[] areas;`
This is my first request, sorry if I made some format mistake.

Comment: You forgot to provide the data type of the column and your version of Postgres. `String[]` is not a valid Postgres type. I suppose you mean `text[]`? And do you want to aggregate all attributes from all rows into one array or just attributes from one row?

Comment: yes, i use postgres 9.4 and the String[] areas is the array where i will put the text attributes. I want to aggregate all attributes of a column

Answer (score 7):

You can use an [array constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
select array(
select zone
from mytable) 
as areas;
```

Comment: I feel `array_agg()` is a bit more convenient, no need to use a subquery, for example.

Comment: @dezso: The [array constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) (which is not an "operator"!) is typically faster to build a single array. So this is actually the best technique.

Comment: I've just made a small test where I see the two producing the exact same query plan, therefore the same execution time.